# Как работать с одним окном, если в программе несколько окон в PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть у меня программа, в которой с три окна. Я не понимаю как работать только с одним окном (выводить текст, работать с кнопками).

вот код: **main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from ui_inst import Ui_Inst
from ui_uch import Ui_Uch                           

class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(443, 293)

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 321, 51))
        self.lineEdit1.setStyleSheet("")
        self.lineEdit1.setText("")
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 421, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 141, 58))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 321, 58))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Ui_Start"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Ui_Start", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Введите номер и букву класса:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "инструкция"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Найти класс"))


class MyInst(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Inst):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyInst, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
class MyUch(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Uch):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyUch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)       


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.uch)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.inst = MyInst()
        self.inst.show()
    def uch(self):
        self.uch = MyUch()
        self.uch.show()
        self.lineEdit2.setText("1")

    



StyleSheet = '''
QPushButton {
    font: bold italic 16pt 'Comic Sans MS';
    background-color: silver;
    width: 75px ;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background: #C9C0BB; 
}            
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: blue;
}

'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                          

    file = QtCore.QFile("dark.qss")                                
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**ui_inst.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Inst(object):
    def setupUi(self, Inst):
        Inst.setObjectName("Ui_Inst")
        Inst.resize(1111, 883)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Inst)                        
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 1111, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.text_inctru = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Inst)
        self.text_inctru.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 1071, 811))
        self.text_inctru.setObjectName("text_inctru")

        self.retranslateUi(Inst)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Inst)                      

    def retranslateUi(self, Inst):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Inst.setWindowTitle(_translate("Inst", "Inst"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Inst", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
        \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC- 
        html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style 
        type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font- 
        size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; 
        margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text- 
        indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:22pt;\">Инструкция</span></p> 
        </body></html>"))
```

---

**ui_uch.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Uch(object):
    def setupUi(self, Uch):
        Uch.setObjectName("Uch")
        Uch.resize(718, 336)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Uch)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 611, 81))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit1")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Uch)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 140, 341, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 27pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Uch)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 222, 601, 61))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 45pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Uch)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 601, 41))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 25pt \"Molot\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Uch)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Uch)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Uch", "Uch"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Uch", "Выбрать ученика"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Uch", "Задать вопрос"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Uch", "Отвечает ученик:"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше основное окно создано классом `Main` и тем,
что вы закачали в него(self.setupUi(self)) из объекта `Ui_Start`.

К объектам этого главного окна вы обращаетесь так:

```
self.lineEdit1 ...    например, self.lineEdit1.text()
self.textEdit ...     например, self.textEdit.setHtml("<b>Привет Мир</b>")
self.pushButton_2 ... например, self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
self.pushButton ...   например, self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.uch)
```

При нажатии на кнопку `self.pushButton_2` вы создаете другое окно
и это будет объект `self.inst`.
К атрибутам этого(self.inst) объекта вы можете обращаться так:

```
self.inst.textEdit ...
self.inst.text_inctru ...
```

При нажатии на кнопку `self.pushButton` вы создаете другое окно
и это будет объект `self.uch`.
К атрибутам этого(self.uch) объекта вы можете обращаться так:

```
self.uch.lineEdit ...
self.uch.pushButton ...
self.uch.pushButton_2 ...
self.uch.label ...
```

Эти другие окна будут `ОКНАМИ` , потому что виджет,
который не имеет родителя будет окном.
Чтобы показать эти ДРУГИЕ ОКНА вы должны выполнить 
`self.inst.show()` или `self.uch.show()` соответственно.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui_inst import Ui_Inst
from ui_uch import Ui_Uch                           

class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(443, 293)

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 321, 51))
        self.lineEdit1.setStyleSheet("")
        self.lineEdit1.setText("")
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 421, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 141, 58))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 321, 58))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Ui_Start"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Ui_Start", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Введите номер и букву класса:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "инструкция"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Найти класс"))


class MyInst(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Inst):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyInst, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MyUch(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Uch):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyUch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)       


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.uch)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.inst = MyInst()
        self.inst.show()

    def uch(self):
        self.uch = MyUch()
        self.uch.show()
#        self.lineEdit2.setText("1")    # у вас нет объета `self.lineEdit2` !
        self.uch.lineEdit.setText(self.lineEdit1.text())                       # <<<-----<


StyleSheet = '''
QPushButton {
    font: bold italic 16pt 'Comic Sans MS';
    background-color: silver;
    width: 75px ;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background: #C9C0BB; 
}            
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: blue;
}

'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                          

    file = QtCore.QFile("dark.qss")                                
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот оно как! Спасибо!